# How to edit devise varification message and remove "email" text from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We are using devise gem on ruby on rails for user account. If anyone click on our verification link 3 days later, we can see this message -

```
Email needs to be confirmed within 3 days, please request a new one
```

we are seeing like this cause on the **config/locales/devise.en.yml** there is -

```
confirmation_period_expired: "needs to be confirmed within %{period}, please request a new one"
```

But I have changed the confirmation_period_expired variable like this -

```
confirmation_period_expired: " hello world"
```

but i can see the verification message like this -

```
Email hello world
```

Hope you understand the problem. by default "email" text is comming. I want to remove this.

I can see on the devise gem, [this file](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/bc6361ab9bd809d8bf51fe2092da6fcb8b495adc/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb) is responsible for automatic adding "email" text.

Now just say me how can I remove the by default "email" text from the devise varification message?

Comment: In `config/locales/devise.en.yml` it stores simple localized strings. It helps users to show same messages in different languages. I think you need to remove `confirmable` from your model and remigrate it, if you don't want to use mail confirmation. To change mail messages from mails, you need to generate devise's views. It will create `views/devise/mailers/` where `html.erb` files are located.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem on devise helper you will see a method resource.errors.full_messages

you have to rename it resource.errors.messages